# clarification on accumulation points

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A=\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4},\ldots\}$. Then the point $0$ is an accumulation point of $A$. The limit point $0$ does not belong to $A$. Also, $A$ does not contain any other limit points.

Why doesn't $0$ belong to $A$, is it because there are an infinite amount of open sets $G$ with $0 \in G$? (An accumulation point will never belong to its associated set?)

What is the difference between open set and neighborhood, isn't every neighborhood an open set?

How can you tell that there are no more accumulation points in $A$?

Many thanks.

Comment: $0$ doesn't belong to $A$ because of the definition of $A$. There is no need to understand accumulation points at this part. Closed sets contains all its accumulation points. Some people use 'open set' and 'neighborhood' as the same, but they're slightly different. I don't think is needed to define an open set.A neighborhood of a point $x$ is a set $V$ containing an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subset V$. The neighborhood itself can be an open set, a closed set, both, or none of them. For example, $\left[ -1,1\right]$ is a neighborhood of $0$ since $0\in(-1/2,1/2)\subset\left[-1,1\right]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An accumulation point of a set **can** belong to the set. Change your example to the set $B$, where $B$ is $A$ together with $0$. Then $0$ is an accumulation point of $B$ and is in $B$.

But an accumulation point of a set need not belong to the set. Your $A$ gives one such example.

That there are no other accumulation points of $A$ can be shown as follows. Suppose that $a$ is an accumulation point of $A$. Then for any $\epsilon$, there are infinitely many elements of $A$ that are within $\epsilon$ of $a$.

Suppose that first that $a\ne 0$. We show that $a$ cannot be an accumulation point of $A$. Let $\epsilon=|a|/2$. Then there are **no** elements of $A$ within $\epsilon$ of $a$. So $a$ cannot be an accumulation point of $A$.

If $a$ is positive, pick $\epsilon=a/2$. Then every number which is within $\epsilon$ of $a$ is $\gt a/2$. There are only finitely many $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\gt a/2$, so $a$ cannot be an accumulation point of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the element of $A$ are the numbers that have the form $\frac{1}{n}$ so saying $0\in A$ means that theres's some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that 
$$\frac{1}{n}=0$$
which's obviously impossible.

An accumulation point belong to the closure of the set and a set with all it's accumulation points is exactly the closure of the set.